# Specific MAC address doesn't receive ARP reply from switch

Tags: networking

Switch is a Nortel 5520

PC is Windows 7, with Intel 82579LM adapter

When PC was first attached to network, it could not ping gateway(switch).  Turns out it was broadcasting for the gateway's MAC address, but never got a response.  Tonnes of testing later, if I just change one number on the MAC address of the adapter, it receives a reply from the switch and can ping the gateway.

Why doesn't the native MAC address work?

Update: Just the vendor portion is the determining factor.  As long as it starts with 2C-59-E5, it will not work.  2C-58-E5 will.

Update 2: Pinging anything in the same subnet works, just pinging the gateway interface of the switch doesn't happen.  Tried on multiple drops, and there are other devices on those drops.

Comment: Is there any valid MAC address other than the native MAC address that didn't work?

Comment: Check the switch's [mac security](http://blog.michaelfmcnamara.com/2011/11/ethernet-routing-switch-mac-address-security/) settings.

Comment: Mac security on the switch is set to disabled

Comment: Did you clear your arp table with an `arp -d` before trying again?  Also try disabling any offload options in the network adapter's driver properties, and you might even go so far as to uninstall/reinstall the device from `devmgmt.cpl` to eliminate any software/driver issues.

Comment: Have cleared the table and won't ever resolve.  Tried multiple drivers, and ran live linux to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my 5520 and the Surface 3.  My issue is resolved!  It turned out to be a bug (The switch did not learn MAC address of the format xx:59:xx:xx:xx:xx (wi00870509).  This is resolved in v6.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

The native MAC address doesn't work because someone set the gateway to use that same MAC address. You can't have two devices using the same MAC address on the same Ethernet network.

Comment: I wish it were true.  The MAC address is 2C-59-E5-xx-xx-xx, but if I change 2C to 3C, it still doesn't work.  If I change 59 to 58, it does.

Comment: @Blego: Obviously a multicast MAC is not going to work! Why would you even test like that?!

Comment: See updated question

Comment: You updated the question with conclusions rather than data. That's not helpful. Did any valid MAC address other than the native MAC not work? If so, please give us the details.

Comment: 2C-59-E5 with any random numbers/letters afterwards will not work.  2C-58-E5 with any random numbers/letters afterwards will.